# Incompatible Types - found:int required:boolean on timer.schedule run() curInterval

Tags: java

Please fix it incompatible type require int found boolean on timer.schedule run() curInterval,What's wrong with my code?

```
 public class HeartbeatPacket implements HeartbeatStop {
        private final String TAG = getClass().getSimpleName();
        private int curInterval = 0;
        private HeartbeatStop heartbeatStop = null;
        private final int setInterval;
        private Timer timer;

        public HeartbeatPacket(HeartbeatStop heartbeatStop, int setInterval) {
            this.heartbeatStop = heartbeatStop;
            this.curInterval = setInterval;
            this.setInterval = this.curInterval;
        }

        public void callStopFun() {
            if (this.heartbeatStop != null) {
                this.heartbeatStop.callStopFun();
            }
        }

        public void recover() {
            synchronized (this) {
                this.curInterval = this.setInterval;
            }
        }

        private void run() {
            if (this.timer == null) {
                Log.e(this.TAG, "null == timer");
            } else {
                this.timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                    public void run() {
                        synchronized (this) {
    //this is the problem section
                            if (HeartbeatPacket.this.curInterval = HeartbeatPacket.this.curInterval - 1 < 0) {
                                HeartbeatPacket.this.callStopFun();
                                HeartbeatPacket.this.recover();
                                HeartbeatPacket.this.stop();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }, 0, 1000);
            }
        }

        public void start() {
            recover();
            this.timer = new Timer();
            run();
        }

        public void stop() {
            this.timer.cancel();
            this.timer = null;
        }``
    }
```

I think the Java compiler should have complained about the 
if(HeartbeatPacket.this.curInterval = HeartbeatPacket.this.curInterval - 1 < 0) . Did you happen to see some compilation error message?

Comment: or in other words: you are missing a pair of parenthesis around the assignment within the `if`-clause

Comment: look very closely at your if condition: `if (HeartbeatPacket.this.curInterval = HeartbeatPacket.this.curInterval - 1 < 0)`

Comment: Single = means assign value, ends up being a number.  If expects a boolean, so use == to compare numbers

Comment: @HithamS.AlQadheeb look closely. There is a binary comparison (`<`) in the expression. Problem is that `<` takes precedence wrt. the assignment.

Comment: He is not shifting with << or >>.  It ends up assigning an int to curInterval if I am not mistaken.

Comment: Still same ,edit my code the show me

Comment: How about  curInterval=curInterval-1;                           if(curInterval<0)  {    }

Answer (score 1):

The operator order of precedence is not what you think it is, especially with `=` and `<`. The comparison is done first, resulting in a `boolean` type, which is then assigned to an `int` field -- which is illegal.

In general, it's not a good idea to combine assignment and/or modification of a variable within the if conditions. It's hard to read, and error-prone (as seen here). Change your value before the if, and then do compare to the plain value.